# What is the difference between regedit and gpedit.msc?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, regedit, gpedit

From my limited knowledge, it seems that gpedit.msc and regedit accomplish the same goal for me. What exactly are the differences? Which is more powerful? Which is more dangerous to play with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not the same, Regedit is a program for managing windows registry. Windows Registry is a hierarchical database that stores configuration settings and options on Microsoft Windows operating systems

Gpedit.msc is a program to manage Windows group policies. Group Policy provides the centralized management and configuration of operating systems, applications, and users' settings in an Active Directory environment.

You can read more about windows group policy here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy

and read more about windows registry here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry